# Two Gesture Recognisers on a Single View?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

I have tried adding both a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and `UILongPresGestureRecognizer` to a single `UIView` and the second one doesn't appear to be used.

Is it possible to have two gestures on a single view?

Comment: Works for me. Can you show your exact code?

Comment: It is possible to have any number of gestures on a single view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can have multiple gesture recognizers on a single view.
In your case the pan GR triggers when you tap the view and move the finger. The long press GR triggers when you tap the view and don't move the finger. I guess your long press GR fails because of a tiny movement of the finger that is recognized as a pan.
You could try to set the `allowableMovement` property of the long press GR, which determines the maximum movement of the fingers on the view before the gesture fails, to a higher value. Then, both GR should trigger.